# has_many through with radio buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

Struggling to get a has_many :through relationship working properly with a form that has the relationship represented by radio buttons.

The relationship describes a Job which can have various Metadata associated with it and those Metadata can be of different Types.  The idea behind this model is that I will eventually be able to add other Metadata to Jobs of other types say a Category of some sort or of value without having to add new tables, etc.

In this instance I have a form to submit a job, with one of the fields being Job Type (Full Time, Part Time, Consulting, Freelance) represented by four radio buttons.

So when you save in the DB you'd have in the corresponding tables:

```
jobs
 id - 1
 title - "Rails Developer"

jobs_metadata
 job_id - 1
 metadata_id - 1

metadata
 id - 1
 description - "Full Time"
 metadatum_type_id - 1

metadatum_types
 id - 1
 description - "Job Type"
```

Here is a summary of my models:

**Job Model**

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :jobs_metadata
   has_many :metadata, :through => :jobs_metadata
```

**Metadatum (singular of Metadata) Model**

```
class Metadatum < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :metadata_type
   has_many :jobs_metadata
   has_many :jobs, :through => :jobs_metadata
```

**JobMetadatum Model** <-- I may add other fields to this table, hence the :through

```
class JobsMetadatum < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :job
   belongs_to :metadatum
```

**MetadataType Model** <--not needed in example, but included for completeness

```
class MetadataType < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :metadata
```

Here is the code representing the radio buttons in the Job view

**View code**

```
<% @job_types.each do |job_type| %>
  <%= radio_button_tag("job[metadatum_ids]", job_type.id) %>
  <%= job_type.description %>&nbsp;
<% end %>
```

When I save the form - everything seems to populate properly, however when I switch to edit mode, the radio button corresponding to the value in jobs_metadata is not checked.

So I supposed my question is twofold:

1. Have I defined the relationship correctly in the above?  Am I doing this "The Rails Way"?
2. Am I defining the form radio buttons correctly - and if so, how do I get them to properly check the value when reading from the DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying the third option in your call to radio_button_tag to make it selected:

```
<%= radio_button_tag("job[metadatum_ids]", job_type.id, true) %>
```

See here for more details: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-radio_button_tag

Obviously you want it to be true based off a test, so you could define methods on your job object like

```
def full_time?
  self.metadata.include?(Metadata.find(1))
end
```

And then:

```
<%= radio_button_tag("job[metadatum_ids]", job_type.id, job.full_time?) %>
```

My example might not be exactly what you want, but you hopefully get the idea.

Comment: Thanks!  But how would I do this when I don't know the number of values for Metadata?  I'm looping through a list of all Metadatum of Type "Job Type" in order to generate my radio buttons (4 of them).  I don't want to create a method for each possible value, right?